# how to adjust x axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph like this[image]

The data on the x axis means hours, so I want the x axis to set as 0, 24, 48, 72.....instead of the value now, which is difficult to see the data between [0,100]

```
fig1 = plt.figure()  
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.plot(x,y,'b-')
```

According to the the first answer, I got this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) :

```
xlocs, xlabs = plt.xticks()
```

put in xlocs your range, and in xlabs what you want to display.

then:

```
 plt.xticks(xlocs, xlabs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it solved my problem, this xticks only change the labels ,I upload the new graph I got, I want the data to be displayed more scatter, not just the label

Comment: From the graph you show, it looks like you incorrectly used xticks, you should do something like this instead:
plt.xticks([0,24,48,72,96,120],[0,24,48,72,96,120])

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to changes the limits of the plotting display - for that use `xlim` (and `ylim` for the other axis). To change the xticks themselves is provided in the answer by @fp. Show below is an example using without/with `xlim`:

```
# Sample data
import numpy as np
N = 2000
X = np.random.gamma(.5,size=N)*100

import pylab as plt

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.hist(X,bins=300)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.hist(X,bins=300)
plt.xlim(0,100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The size of the plot can be changed by setting the dynamic rc settings of Matplotlib. These are stored in a dictionary named rcParams. The size of the plot figure is stored with the key figure.figsize.

As an example, to get and set the size of a Matplotlib plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] #Get current size
print "Current size:", fig_size           #Prints: [8.0, 6.0]
fig_size[0] = 12                          #Set figure width to 12 and height to 9
fig_size[1] = 9
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
```