# add more labels to the x axis python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is my original graph:
[image]

I didn't change the xticklabels or anything, I only did `plot(x,y)`, the labels are automatically generated according to the x values.

However I want to change the x label to [0,24,48,72....480,504]

This is what I did

```
ax.plot(x1,y1)

xlabel =[]
xinterval = np.arange(0,504,24) 
ax.set_xticks=(xinterval)
ax.set_xticklabels(xinterval)
```

And the result is:
[image]

which is obviously wrong, could anyone help?

Comment: `ax.set_xticks=(xinterval)` - the `=` seems out of place.

Is it in your original code?

Comment: This looks EXTREMELY similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109648/how-to-adjust-x-axis-in-matplotlib/12110715#12110715. Can you spell out what is different between the two posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo; it's supposed to be `ax.set_xticks(xinterval)`, without the `=`.

No need for the `set_xticklabels` command.

Comment: +1 ha-ha didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me

```
from string import lowercase


xs = range(0,504,24)
plot(xs, [sin(x) for x in xs])
locs,labels = xticks(xs, [lowercase[xs.index(x)] for x in xs])
```

slightly contorted example but at least the labels come out correctly as `string`s and seem to be in the correct place.