# Editing Python plot surface ticks and their frequency

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

### **Gist of my question:**

I have data that I am `plot_surface`-ing with python. How should I change the values of my `xticks` and `yticks` and perhaps their frequency?

### **Details of my question**

I have data such as [this](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13223318/dcm_2350micrometer_profile_i.dat). I had to upload my data file to dropbox as it is too large to reproduce here and I am not sure that a "minimal example" would do justice.

I have several such data files in a folder (think several dozens really) on which I run a python script that loads each such data file and creates a surface plot. My python code looks like this:

### python code

```
import os
import glob
import sys
import subprocess
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

from numpy import *
from numpy.random import rand
from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
from pylab import *

for fname in glob.glob('*profile*.dat'):
    with open(fname) as f:
        data = np.loadtxt(fname)
        z = np.array(data)

    x,y = np.meshgrid(range(data.shape[0]), range(data.shape[1]))

    fig = plt.figure()

    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5,cmap="binary",linewidth=0.1)
    ax.set_zlim3d(0.0,4.0)

    ax.set_xlabel('X',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    ax.set_zlabel('h(X,T)',fontsize=16,fontweight="bold")
    savefig('/home/uid/Desktop/'+fname.replace(".dat","")+'.eps',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)
    savefig('/home/uid/Desktop/'+fname.replace(".dat","")+'.pdf',figsize=(5,5),dpi=600)

print "Profile plots have been saved!"
"EOF"
```

The plot looks like so:

[image: Surface plot generated by my code]

### Observations/What I am trying to accomplish:

What I need to do is change the xticks and yticks to other numbers. What is shown in the plot are actually "grid points" used. My X and Y lengths are actually "50 units" each with about 265 grid points used in each direction.

How do I change the xticks and yticks to show "0... 50" on the x and y axis?

I apologize if this question seems sophomoric but I have been searching for ways to go about it but have come up with only a minimal set of answers. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12143977/957560) [2](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#setting-ticks).

Comment: When you output this to eps does the back wall become a solid plane instead of having axis lines for x and z?? I am having that problem but only occurs to eps output and not pdf output. Since you are doing both here I'm wondering if the above picture is how it looks on both pdf and eps output?

Comment: shading=True is often a good parameter to pass to mplot3d plots. Antialiasing=True as stated is probably better but that can often help as well. There are different types of shading too but usually the default is the best. rstride and cstride set where the surface contour lines go every so many data points in the x and y direction. With 250 points in each direction. Try something like 10 for a total of 25 contour lines in each direction or whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the 266 points in each data dimension (i.e. `data.shape = (266, 266)`) represent `0...50`, then you can simply scale the `meshgrid()` output:

```
x,y = np.meshgrid(range(data.shape[0]), range(data.shape[1]))
x *= 50./data.shape[0]
y *= 50./data.shape[1]
```

If you also need to modify their frequency, then just directly modify `xticks()` and `yticks()` manually or programmatically as suggested by the [second answer you found](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#setting-ticks):

```
ax.set_xticks([0., 15., 30., 45.])
num_ticks = 5.
ax.set_yticks(arange(num_ticks)/(num_ticks-1) * 50)
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Thank you! I was just doing: `ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70])`. Obviously,this wouldnt have been the prettiest piece of code!

Comment: Also, why are my output plots so "coarse"? I tried playing around with  lower values for `rstride` and `cstride` but to no avail! `:(`

Comment: Don't know about that. I actually get only the axes plotted when I run your code, not the surface plot. The corresponding error is `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. Since the question wasn't related to this, I didn't dig deeper into it. Can you confirm that the posted code doesn't result in the same error for you?

Comment: Try passing `antialiased=True` to `plot_surface()`.

Comment: Hmmm... should have thought of that! `;)` thanks though. I will try that and see how it goes.

Comment: It's sometimes hard to figure out which extended keyword arguments (`**kwargs`) apply to certain functions such as [`plot_surface()`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface). I realized `antialiased` was an argument through a [linked demo (py script)](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.py).